# MongoDB Disabling Auto Split

Tags: mongodb, nosql

We have a process that will bulk ingest around 6 billion documents of 500 bytes each. We are finding that the performance really tends to drop off around the 4-5bn document mark with the lions share of the time spent splitting chunks which prevents insertions during that time.

Does it make sense to increase the chunk size from the default of 64MB and / or to disable auto splitting altogether as a temporary solution?

Comment: Part of the answer is commented on in the docs but we'd really appreciate a second opinion on the issue: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/sharding-data-partitioning/

Comment: you can increase chunk size or you can disable autoSplitting entirely. This is only safe if you have presplit the collection and the existing chunks are well balanced across the shards already. if not then moving bigger chunks will be problematic.